# Android can't serialize Kotlin lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, jvm

we can read lambda function are serialize by default (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/are-closures-serializable/1620),
but I getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.dialogfragment.Arguments)
```

my class Arguments:

```
class Arguments(val function: ()-> Unit) : Serializable
```

What is wrong with my lambda ?
(I got this error when Android need to kill my fragment because low of memory :) )

Comment: Android does not "kill" fragments due to low memory conditions. Android terminates processes due to low memory conditions. Regarding your `Serializable` problem, I would not expect attempting to write a lambda expression to disk to work, and I would not expect attempting to save a lambda expression in the saved instance state `Bundle` to work.

Comment: but functional interfaces saved into Bundle works

Comment: The most likely problem is that your lambda contains a reference to a non-serializable object.

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually serializing and putting lambda expression into `Fragment. arguments` works just fine. But when `onSaveInstanceState` is called app crashes which is abnormal. I mean how come it works when serializing/deserializing from/to `Fragment.arguments` but it crashes when `onSaveInstanceState` is called?

Comment: @Farid: "Actually serializing and putting lambda expression into Fragment. arguments works just fine" -- the rest of your comment illustrates why this is not the case. The saved instance state `Bundle` is to be passed across process boundaries, and you cannot pass code that way.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I am quite sure that is the case but how is that even possible that everything works just fine when serializing/deserializing a lambda function to/from `Fragment.arguments` that has reference to a non-serializable object but when `onSaveInstanceState` is called it crashes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting. One more thing, why (or how) is it possible to serialize a lambda function that has a reference to a non-serializable object. I mean why a code like this `Bundle().putSerializable("KEY", [LAMBDA WITH REFERENCE TO A NON-SERIALIZABLE OBJECT])` works?

Comment: @Farid: I do not know, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize or parcel something you need to ensure every field is serializable or parcelable.
In your case you are trying to serialize `val function: ()-> Unit` which is not serializable. Unfortunately, you can't make function serializable. You should rethink this argument class and pass something different. Probably you can get some parameter which leads to making a decision and then invoking a function in your fragment.

Comment: Who says Kotlin lambdas are not serializable? https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/are-closures-serializable/1620